# How to convert a PowerPoint ppt file into HTML files?

Tags: command-line, conversion, html

I have to find a free, gratis command line solution to convert primary Microsoft PowerPoint presentations into HTML files (1 HTML file per foil) on Linux (Debian, OpenSuse). It would be nice if the solution supports OpenOffice Impress presentations as well but this is not necessary.

What is/are solution/s for this matter?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with UNIX/Linux? More like SU.

Comment: Linux based solution. But maybe you're right.

Comment: see http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/1726/bulk-file-conversion-using-command-line/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use pptHTML:

http://www.ma.utexas.edu/restricted-resources/utma-doc/xlHtml/pptHtml.txt

For debian based distros:
http://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/ppthtml

The C Source for the xlhtml package:
http://prdownloads.sf.net/chicago/xlhtml-0.4.9.3.tgz

ppthtml is an executable installed through the same package.

Comment: Thanks! `xlhtml` is the name for OpenSuse, right?

Comment: xlhtml is for Excel. While pptHtml is for Ppt files.

Comment: Awww fail. You're right. But I can't find nighter pptHTML at OpenSuse nor its (non Debian) source code to compile for OpenSuse.

Comment: I could find the windows executable for the same. Maybe you could run it on wine?

Comment: C Source for xlhtml. It contains the ppthtml executable in the same package. 
http://prdownloads.sf.net/chicago/xlhtml-0.4.9.3.tgz

Answer (score 0):

[jodconverter](https://github.com/sbraconnier/jodconverter/) is what you're looking for.

**JODConverter**, the Java OpenDocument Converter, converts documents between different office formats.
It leverages [Apache OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org) or [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org), which provide arguably the best free import/export filters for OpenDocument and Microsoft Office formats available today.

**JODConverter** automates all conversions supported by OpenOffice/LibreOffice. Supported conversions include:

```
| Document Type | Input Format                    | Output Format                                 |
| ------------- | ------------------------------- | --------------------------------------------- |
| Text          | DOC, DOCX, ODT, OTT, RTF, TEXT  | DOC, DOCX, HTML, ODT, OTT, PDF, PNG, RTF, TXT |
| Spreadsheet   | CSV, ODS, OTS, TSV, XLS, XLSX   | CSV, HTML, ODS, OTS, PDF, PNG, TSV, XLS, XLSX |
| Presentation  | ODP, OTP, PPT, PPTX             | HTML, ODP, OTP, PDF, PNG, PPT, PPTX, SWF      |
| Drawing       | ODG, OTG                        | ODG, OTG, PDF, PNG, SWF                       |
| Other         | HTML                            | DOC, DOCX, HTML, ODT, OTT, PDF, PNG, RTF, TXT |
```

**JODConverter** can be used in many different ways:

- As a Java library, embedded in your own Java application.
- As a command line tool, possibly invoked from your own scripts.
- As a simple web application: upload your input document, select the desired format and download the converted version.

Comment: Note that even though the question asked for "command line" options, if you just download and run LibreOffice or OpenOffice, you can open a power point presentation in it, and then export it to html, if you're not into the command line - [This page in the LibreOffice docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/simpress/guide/html_export.html) tells you more